# Upgrade/downgrade subscription using cordova-plugin-purchase

Tags: android, cordova, in-app-purchase, cordova-plugins, in-app-billing

I'm trying to implement upgrade/downgrade of subscription on android using the fovea cordova-plugin-purchase (https://github.com/j3k0/cordova-plugin-purchase).

According to google documentation, using the getBuyIntentToReplaceSkus() method, you can subscribe to a new product and automatically unsubscribe from others, but i don't know if this plugin covers this method.

Has anyone been able to upgrade/downgrade a subscription with the cordova plugin?